# Large matrix coefficients and large RHS warning in Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, warnings, gurobi

I'm running an optimization algorithm in Python using Gurobi with a pretty large dataset. The imported csvs contain a lot of zeroes and a lot of large values. I'm receiving a warning after the presolve that the model contains large matrix coefficients and a large right hand side. What can I do to fix this? Can I simply scale down all non-zero values by some factor?

```
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.5.1 build v9.5.1rc2 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 1116052 rows, 575004 columns and 1984260 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x223d0add
Variable types: 355740 continuous, 219264 integer (1024 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [8e-02, 2e+10]
  Objective range  [2e-13, 2e-06]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e-01, 2e+10]
Warning: Model contains large matrix coefficients
Warning: Model contains large rhs
         Consider reformulating model or setting NumericFocus parameter
         to avoid numerical issues.
Found heuristic solution: objective 143424.26885
Presolve removed 1116022 rows and 574935 columns
Presolve time: 1.34s
Presolved: 30 rows, 69 columns, 120 nonzeros
Found heuristic solution: objective 135423.71070
Variable types: 57 continuous, 12 integer (0 binary)

Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 1.75 seconds (1.28 work units)
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 2: 135424 143424 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.354237107007e+05, best bound 1.354237107007e+05, gap 0.0000%
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs on or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

A good way to scale the model is to use better units, i.e. instead of cents use million dollars. Or instead of grams, use metric tons.